# Processing the data in a matrix in r

Tags: r, matrix

I'm completely new to r and thus the issues. I've a matrix with the following data

```
[1,] NA                  "/home/psycodelic/Desktop/r_source//AAIT.csv" 
 [2,] "50.6606864064485"  "/home/psycodelic/Desktop/r_source//AAPL.csv" 
 [3,] "20.697618553608"   "/home/psycodelic/Desktop/r_source//BSFT.csv" 
 [4,] "0.585775171228343" "/home/psycodelic/Desktop/r_source//BSPM.csv" 
 [5,] "1.07713703069294"  "/home/psycodelic/Desktop/r_source//BSQR.csv" 
 [6,] NA                  "/home/psycodelic/Desktop/r_source//CAPN.csv" 
 [7,] NA                  "/home/psycodelic/Desktop/r_source//CAPNW.csv"
```

I'm trying to do the following with this matrix

~ extract the file name, ie the portion just adjacent to .csv

~ remove all entries containing NA

~ convert the values to integers

~ sort as per the values in the descending order(lowest on top)

~ create a new matrix with only the top 10(ie least 10) values and print it.

Can someone help me with this.

Comment: No one is going to write your code for you, tell us what you tried and where you are getting stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE:** Your question as it stands is not appropriate for this site. You should include a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/3005513). Include code that you've tried and where it's causing you trouble. *At this point, you're likely to continue getting down votes, and your question may potentially get closed.* Be aware of that. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to improve your question.

**That said**, you're new to R and I will try to help you get started on this. But **please** consult the help center to get started on Stack Overflow.

---

Let's assume your matrix is stored with the name `mat`. First convert it to a data frame.

```
df <- as.data.frame(mat)
```

This will have columns called `V1` and `V2`. You can rename them if you want to using `colnames(df) <- c("whatever", "something")`. I'll proceed assuming you've kept the original names.

Now get the file name from the second column.

```
df$file.name <- with(df, tail(strsplit(V2, "/")[[1]], n=1))
```

There's a lot going on here, so let's look at it one step at a time.

```
> strsplit("/home/psycodelic/Desktop/r_source//AAPL.csv", "/")
[[1]]
[1] ""  "home"  "psycodelic"  "Desktop"  "r_source"  ""  "AAPL.csv"
```

This is a *list* with one element. We can get that single element using `[[1]]`. That element contains a vector of strings which result from splitting the input at the `/` character.

You only want the file name, which is the last part of the file path. Thus we can get the last element of the vector using `tail(..., n=1)`.

`with(df, ...)` ensures that `V2` is interpreted in the context of the data frame `df`.

So at this point `df` has three columns: the two originals, plus one containing the file names. The next step is to remove the `NA` values. We can do this using the `na.omit()` function.

```
df <- na.omit(df)
```

You can blindly convert the floats in `V1` to integers using `as.integer()`.

```
df$V1 <- as.numeric(df$V1)
```

Getting close! Sort ascending like  so:

```
df <- df[with(df, order(V1)), ]
```

Now create a new data frame and print it.

```
(df2 <- head(df, n=10))
```

Surrounding an assignment in parentheses will both print it and assign it.